# Execute Jar file from C# on remote machine via WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service running on remote machine, in my application from another machine I can connect to the remote machine and edit for example files, another option that I added is to execute `Jar` file:

```
public void Run()
{
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
        "java.exe", "-jar D:\\File.jar")
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    Process proc;

    if ((proc = Process.Start(processInfo)) == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("??");
    }

    proc.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    proc.Close();
}
```

This command works file on local machine and i can run my `Jar` file. This is not the case with the remote machine and in this case nothing happen.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: The remote machine, can it access the file to get response, an return it via WCF?

Comment: I did not understand what you are asking

Comment: if you have a server that you are connecting it via WCF , can the server access the file and return you the requested command?

Comment: by saying server you mean the machine that running the WCF service ?

Comment: yep. the service on the server

Comment: Yes, this machine have access to the local file

Comment: so access the file from the service and transfer your result to the connected client

Comment: What do you mean access the file from the service ? my function did not doing that (Run())?

Comment: the run method is on the client connecting to the WCFR service , right?

Comment: Yes, can you show me code example how to do that ?

Comment: The Run method is inside my service implementation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40069/discussion-between-izikon-and-user2214609)